# Is there a way to replace the values by NaN of one dataframe in the corresponding position of NaN of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two 2-D dataframe of same size.
One of the dataframe has NaN values in various positions.
Now, I want to replace the elements of the other dataframe as NaN corresponding to the position of the NaN values of the earlier dataframe.

Dataframe - 1
0    |  1 |   2 |   3  |
:----|:---|:----|:-----|
NaN  | NaN|  NaN|  NaN |
1.23 |1.25|5.05 | 0    |

Dataframe - 2
0    |  1 |   2 |   3  |
:----|:---|:----|:-----|
2.05 |1.98|5.45 |  6.23|
1.23 |1.25|5.05 | 0    |

In this example I want to replace the first row of Dataframe - 2 with NaN value i.e I want to replace the element of Dataframe - 2 with NaN corresponding to the positions of NaN value of Dataframe-1.
In my real problem the size of the Dataframe is 17515 X 365

Expected output
Dataframe - 2
0    |  1 |   2 |   3  |
:----|:---|:----|:-----|
NaN  |NaN |NaN  |  NaN |
1.23 |1.25|5.05 | 0    |

Comment: Can you please edit you question to format it nicely (see my answer for an example)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
dataframe2.where(~dataframe1.isna(), dataframe1)
```

Or:

```
dataframe2.where(~dataframe1.isna(), float('nan'))
```

```
>>> dataframe1
      0     1     2    3
0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1  1.23  1.25  5.05  0.0

>>> dataframe2
      0     1     2     3
0  2.05  1.98  5.45  6.23
1  1.23  1.25  5.05  0.00
```

output:

```
      0     1     2    3
0   NaN   NaN   NaN  NaN
1  1.23  1.25  5.05  0.0
```